# How to display the last eclapsed time in SqlDevelopper when analysing query

Tags: query-optimization, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

As we can notice in my screenshot , We can see the object name , cost , cadinality and the last_cr_buffers_gets attribut in SqlDevelopper

[image: sql developper display]
But , how to display the last eclapsed time and other attributes?

I'm using Oracle sql developper 4.0 x64

Regards,

Bass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferences->Database->Autotrace/Explain Plan

However this particular column (last_elapsed_time) is on by default. Can it be that it is just scrolled out of view and reappear if you resize those super wide columns?

Comment: Yup scrolled out ! Weird university computers , don't even ask ! Thank you very much for your help